# SugarCRM restriction on custom field

Tags: sugarcrm

i'm totally new to SugarCRM module development, however i have very good knowledge of PHP, ajax and database programming.

Here is my task:I have been asked to create a restriction on a custom field from the clients module.
There is a custom field called identification number, what i need to do is avoid a new client to be saved into the database based on that field, in other words the client has to be unique. It has to display a pop up window saying "that client already exists"

Comment: Could this number be autogenerated instead? Would make this issue much easier to deal with?

Comment: Not really, the number belongs to personal identification number almost like a drivers licence id, thanks for the suggestion anyways

Answer (score 4):

Copy `editviewdefs.php` of Accounts to the `custom` folder and change the custom field definition for `id_number` to this

```
array(
  'name' => 'id_number',
  'displayParams' => 
  array (
    'field' =>   
    array (  
      'onChange' => 'check_is_duplicate(this);',  
    ), 
  ),
),
```

Create a javascript function `check_is_duplicate`

```
function check_is_duplicate(obj) {
  // Call a script via Ajax. Pass values for id and id_number with the request.
  if (o.responseText > 0) {
    alert('duplicate');
    document.getElementById('SAVE').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('SAVE').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

You would have to create the script which would be called via ajax request.
In that script you would have to run a query like -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM accounts 
WHERE deleted = 0 AND id != {$record} AND id_number = {$id_number}
```

Execute the query and return the count.

Afterwards on saving check for duplicates from server side using the `beforeSave` logic hook.

Comment: The best way to include this JS in the page? And how to make the nice alert in the SugarCRM style instead of ugly JS.alert function? Thanks.

Comment: @Kostanos You can include it from a file by using `'templateMeta' => array (
  'includes' => array (
    0 => array (
      'file' => 'modules/module_name/script.js',
    ),
  ),
),`

Comment: or directly in the page `'templateMeta' => array (
  ...
  'javascript' => <<<EOD
  {literal}
  // Your js code 
  {/literal}
EOD;
  ,
),`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom duplicate check by the following code:

```
$dictionary['Account']['duplicate_check']['FilterDuplicateCheck']['filter_template'] = array(
    array(
        '$and' => array(
            array('identification_number' => array('$equals' => '$identification_number')),

        ),
    ),
);
```

Add this code in the file: /custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Vardefs/duplicate_check.php.
Then, perform a quick repair/rebuild.

How it works:
When you enter the identification number and press save, SugarCRM will perform a duplicate check. If duplicates are found, SugarCRM will list the duplicates and you can choose to use the duplicate or ignore.